# Why python function receiving empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function of for saving three lists so it takes those lists as arguments and then writes each of them line by line to a text file.

```
rotor1, rotor1_pos, rotor2, rotor2_pos, rotor3, rotor3_pos = [x for x in range(26)], 0, [x for x in range(26)], 0, [x for x in range(26)], 0

def save_rotors(rpos1=rotor1_pos,rpos2=rotor2_pos,rpos3=rotor3_pos,r1=rotor1[:],r2=rotor2[:],r3=rotor3[:]):
    print(r1,r2,r3)
    with open('rotors.txt.',mode='w') as f:
        f.write(str(rpos1)+'\n')
        for num in r1:
            f.write(str(num)+'\n')

        f.write(str(rpos2)+'\n')
        for num in r2:
            f.write(str(num)+'\n')

        f.write(str(rpos3)+'\n')
        for num in r3:
            f.write(str(num)+'\n')
```

But when I run

```
print(rotor1,rotor2,rotor3)
save_rotors()
```

I find that my lists are correctly populated but inside of save_rotors I have empty lists? As shown above I immediately printing out the r1,r2,r3 arguments so nothing else is happening to the lists, they are only being passed as arguments. My function reads the correct values from the integer valued variables but not the list. My text file ends up looking like

```
0
[]
0
[]
0
[]
```

What is going on here?

Comment: They are defined above the function. 
```rotor1 = [x for x in range(26)]```

Comment: looking at the code here, i cannot see anything wrong with it. can you even reproduce this issue with just the code here in a new session?

Comment: When I run that code on https://onlinegdb.com/Ske1Ba3gB the text file does not look how you described it

Comment: So, I've restarted my computer and run it from several different terminals and the error always reproduces itself for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used a [Mutable Default Argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) Which is defining the lists when the function is defined.

You should instead pass the arguments in by calling the function:

```
def save_rotors(pos1 ,rpos2, rpos3, r1, r2, r3):
    ...

save_rotors(rotor1_pos, rotor2_pos, rotor3_pos, rotor1, rotor2, rotor3)
```

**EDIT**:
After a discussion in chat, we discovered that there may be some non-visible characters in the original source file that were causing the interpreter some grief. Copying and Pasting the code as it appears in the question seems to work just fine. I will leave the original discussion of mutable default arguments here, however since I still feel it is relevant.

Comment: Is that not the same as passing rotor1[:] for example?

Comment: passing `rotor1[:]` passes a copy of the list. But defining it with a reference to the copy is also using a mutable default argument

Comment: If you need a default that is a list it is better to use `def f(x=None)` then check inside the function if a value was passed and set it internally if not.

Comment: I don't totally understand why this causes a problem. Can you explain a little more please?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you're having a problem running it this way, when I run it, it prints out as expected. Did you post your full code? Are the lists mutated by anything external prior to the call? In any case I see no reason to pass the lists in the function definition unless you are trying to preserve their state on multiple iterations.

Comment: What is your environment like? Specific python version, interpreter (cpython, pypy), did you install with something like anaconda?

Comment: Just python 3.7. I do have anaconda installed but I am not calling anything special here

Comment: Passing the arguments explicitly fixed the problem. However, I have similar functions for other variable which use default arguments that are mutables without problem so I'm still confused

Comment: This is an interesting problem... There is definitely something different about this case then. I tried it on python3.6 and 3.7 and it works in both for me, so clearly there is something going on with the execution on your system. How do you invoke the script?

Comment: python3.7 Enig.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196047/discussion-between-alex-and-aaron-zolotor).